# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome battery indicator is showing just a box

Tags: gnome, indicator, battery

My battery indicator in the menu bar is showing just a box for an icon in place of the battery icon - this is the case in the drop down menu too.

I have tried doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

[image: This is the image of my battery indicator & the drop down menu]

What else can I try?

Comment: Sounds like a possible theme and/or package corruption. Please check if other icon themes exhibit the same issue, [perform a package sanity check](/a/57728/175814) and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

tweak tool>appearance>change the icons

change it to other option you will get it right

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the battery and bluetooth icons.

Changing Gnome Tweak Tool -> Fonts -> Scaling factor solved it for me. The whole range between 1.35 to 1.40 was broken for wifi and battery with the Paper icon theme, so I changed it to 1.41. Maybe the panel has some scaling bug or the icon set is suboptimal for this range.